# Parsing ZonedDateTime with Java 8 DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to create a ZonedDateTime with a DateTimeFormatter by using the following pattern `"dd-mm-yyyy'T'HH:mmZ"`:

```
public static ZonedDateTime timeFromDayMonthYearHHmmTZ(String dateTime){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mmZ");
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);
    }
```

Using the previous code, the following expression parses correctly:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime1 = ZonedDateTimeUtils.dateTimeFromDayMonthYearHHmmTZ("25-01-2018T15:30-0100");
```

However, the next expression generates an exception (notice the `:` in the TZ offset):

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime2 = ZonedDateTimeUtils.dateTimeFromDayMonthYearHHmmTZ("25-01-2018T15:30-01:00");
```

My understanding is that `Z` in the pattern `"dd-mm-yyyy'T'HH:mmZ"` should cover both cases? However I am getting the following exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '25-01-2018T15:30-01:00' could not be parsed at index 16
```

Ideally I would like to have a flexible solution where I can parse both patterns.

Comment: `Z` only covers `-0800` while `X` covers `-08; -0800; -08:00`. you can read it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer post it as an answer.... this is what OP needs IMHO

Comment: I was using the following docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html. If you look in the example for the zone offsets, you will see that 08:00 is included for the Z pattern. So this is probably an error in the javadoc?

Comment: `Z` seems to have a problem with the `-` before the offset (only if it includes a `:`). `X` is failing at the `:`. But note that the string in your error message does not match the string in your code

Comment: Yes sorry I corrected that

Comment: seems to be a problem witht the `DateTimeFormatter`, because a `SimpleDateFormat` can parse that string without any problems (using `X`)

Comment: @BigONotation see my updated answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I found, there seems to definitly be a problem with `Z`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851732/datetimeformatter-trouble-with-a-pattern) and in the answer, it uses `XXX` for the offset. I tried it and it is working. I checked a few variations like `X`,`XX`,`Z`,`ZZ` and `ZZZ`, but only `XXX` worked fine.

The complete pattern is `dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mmXXX`

Comment: It seems that the other patterns such as O do not work either.

Answer (score 0):

For this error to be solved, you need to use `X` instead of `Z`, so... `"dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mmX"`

If you look at the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) it explains that:

- `Z` allows for `-0800`
- `X` allows for one of the three `-08; -0800; -08:00`

So for your case being `25-01-2018T15:30-01:00`, you need to use the latter.

Comment: You have sent me a link to SimpleDateFormat. I am using a DateFormatter, and in  the docs provided for DateFormatter, Z can take values such as -08:00

Comment: Maybe you should change to SimpleDateFormat instead? I tested the DateTimeFormatter[1] and out of the following: `V, O, X, x, Z, z`, I could only get `z` to work. Weird, as it shouldn't so maybe this could be a bug on javas side?

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html